# cannot import name 'fpn_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I've installed tensorflow 2.x for using object detection on windows 10 and follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

but this error after run
`python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`
showing.

even run new command
`python model_main_tf2.py --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

Comment: If i am not mistaken that tutorial follows tensorflow 1 and faster rcnn inception is available at tensorflow 1 only. Why not follow this tutorial that shows tf2 object detection api: https://github.com/abdelrahman-gaber/tf2-object-detection-api-tutorial

Comment: DId you download your backbone from the model zoo at tensorflow 2 api: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is no `fpn_b2.py` file in the `object_detection/protos` folder. The protoc command given in the tutorial missed this.

You can run the following from `research` folder in anaconda prompt

`protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\fpn.proto`

Comment: spoiler alert : I also followed the tutorial. If you are using Tensorflow2, the training won't work. TF2 don't support `faster_rcnn_inception_v2`

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Check folder in directory *...\object_detection\protos* and count how many _pb2.py and .protos (don't count init.py and pychance), if they equal then congratulation this forum not solve that problem, but if not go to no.2

**2**. Type this on console
`protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\ YYYY .proto`

what is YYYY..? it's the missing .py in *\object_detection\protos...* to know it check protos and _pb2.py if 1 of protos don't have match, change the YYYY* with that name ( example : I don't have _pb2.py match at anchor_generator.proto, so I type in console `protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto`, and so all)

Answer (score 0):

!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

Your pwd should be 'Tensorflow/models/research

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).